# Changes in dnspy not showing up when I run it

Tags: c#, dnspy

I edited code in an exe using dnspy just like this youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OQiVWJ-TGc) for editing desktop goose. However, my changes do not show up when I run it just like this guy did. However, when I look at the exe code using dotpeek, it shows up there too with my changes in the code (not in the visual representation when I run it). Is there a cache or something that is causing this?

I tried editing the code just like the YouTube video and tried to find related questions on Stack Overflow. I did find one ([Editing IL of C# assembly without source not reflecting changes upon execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543297/editing-il-of-c-sharp-assembly-without-source-not-reflecting-changes-upon-execut)), but they did not say how they resolved their issue, so I need help. Please help! I rly need it!

Comment: They answered their own question saying they found it cached in the GAC. Start > Run > Assembly and search for the Desktop Goose.

Comment: I went there, but I could not find anything with Desktop Goose there.

Comment: Also, they talked about NGEN.exe and Native Image and said it was not installed in the GAC.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I limited to a specific problem and  added a link to better describe it.

Comment: @CoderGuy It's not really specific still. What changes are you adding, how exactly are you doing them. Step by step so one can repro and check if this is correct way

Answer (score 1):

It has got to do something with a cache on the pc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).