# What should I do with this information about dnspy not saving?

Tags: c#, dnspy

When I save code in dnspy, the changes do not show up on the screen. However, when I look through dotpeek too,  my changes in the code are present, but the visible changes on the screen when I run it do not show.

[Editing IL of C# assembly without source not reflecting changes upon execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543297/editing-il-of-c-sharp-assembly-without-source-not-reflecting-changes-upon-execut) answers this, but I do not know what to do with their information. They provide a reason to the problem, but how should I take action based on this reason?

Comment: what happen if you reload the binary in dnSpy?